# Select string value into Year format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing the fields as:

```
State_Code    School_Code    Established_Year    Data_Year
    12        12016837383          1962           2011-12
    12        12018383799          1996           2011-12
    12        12024895748          2007           2011-12
    12        12037849837          1987           2011-12
```

Here, all these fields are of VARCHAR type.

I want to retrieve all schools which were established before the year 1990. I fired this query:

```
Select 
  School_Code, 
  date_format(str_to_date(Established_Year,'%y'),'%y') as Year,   
  date_format(str_to_date(Data_Year,'%y'),'%y') as Data_Year 
from 
  Table1 
WHERE 
  Established_Year < 1990;
```

But it returns this:

```
School_Code    Year    Data_Year
12016837383     19      20
12037849837     19      20
```

I tried to use `CONVERT` function also, as:

```
Select 
  School_Code, 
  Convert(Established_Year, YEAR) as Year 
from 
  Table1 
WHERE 
  Established_Year < 1990;
```

But it throws this error:

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'YEAR' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually convert it to int.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TableName
WHERE  CAST(Established_Year AS UNSIGNED) < 1990
```

**UPDATE 1**

Based on your comment, if you want to retrieve those School_Codes whose Data_Year is before 2010-11, you need to convert `Data_Year` into real date.

```
SELECT School_Code    
FROM   TableName
WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(Data_Year, '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') < DATE('2010-11-01')
```

Comment: Thanks, This solved my problem for the Established_Year field. But if I want to retrieve those School_Codes whose Data_Year is before 2010-11; then how should I do it?

Comment: Actually, Data_Year column shows the year in which the corresponding information about this school was gathered. '2011-12' does not mean that '2011' is year and '12' is a month or a date. It is an year-session. I'm sorry, if I mislead you.

Comment: Data_Year column shows the year in which the corresponding information about this school was gathered. '2011-12' does not mean that '2011' is year and '12' is a month or a date. It is an year-session.